# Defining multiple Foreign Key for the Same table in ASP.NET MVC Core Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two entities in my Core MVC application. There are two Bolge  Id in the BolgeToBolge entity; one of them is FromBolgeFk, the other one is ToBolgeFk.
After `update-database` command in package manager console of Visual Studio 2019, I have an error like this:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_BolgeToBolge_Bolge_ToBolgeFk' on table 'BolgeToBolge' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

my codes:

Bolge.cs Entity Model:

```
public class Bolge
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name ="Bölge")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Required]
        public string BolgeAd { get; set; }
       
        [ForeignKey("Ilce")]
        public int IlceFk { get; set; }
        public virtual Ilce Ilce { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BolgeToBolge> BolgeToBolgeFroms { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BolgeToBolge> BolgeToBolgeToes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Rezervasyon> RezervasyonsFrom { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Rezervasyon> RezervasyonsTo { get; set; }
    }
```

BolgeToBolge Entity:

```
public class BolgeToBolge
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("FromBolge")]
        [InverseProperty("BolgeToBolgeFroms")]
        public int FromBolgeFk { get; set; }
        public virtual Bolge FromBolge { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ToBolge")]
        [InverseProperty("BolgeToBolgeToes")]
        public int ToBolgeFk { get; set; }
        public virtual Bolge ToBolge { get; set; }
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext:DbContext

```
{
 modelBuilder.Entity<BolgeToBolge>()
    .HasKey(BtB=> new {BtB.FromBolgeFk, BtB.ToBolgeFk });

            modelBuilder.Entity<BolgeToBolge>()
                .HasOne(BtB => BtB.FromBolge)
                .WithMany(BtB => BtB.BolgeToBolgeFroms)
                .HasForeignKey(BtB => BtB.FromBolgeFk).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BolgeToBolge>()
                .HasOne(BtB => BtB.ToBolge)
                .WithMany(BtB => BtB.BolgeToBolgeToes)
                .HasForeignKey(BtB => BtB.ToBolgeFk).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which EF version is this? IT's not EF6.

Answer (score 0):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<BolgeToBolge>()
            .HasOne(BtB => BtB.ToBolge)
            .WithMany(BtB => BtB.BolgeToBolgeToes)
            .HasForeignKey(BtB => BtB.ToBolgeFk).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```